# Wooden and metal bed frame disassembly

Tags: bed

I do not see how to take the metal slats out of the wooden part. There are no screws and I cannot lift nor pull them out.  Please help.

[image]

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to use this site. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 4):

They are usually held with a hook on the metal piece and pins in the wood.

The usually to undo them is to lift the metal while holding down on the wood.

If too tight a bit of persuasion using a rubber mallet or a hammer hitting a scrape piece of wood under the metal should loosen them up.

Once loosen might need to wiggle the two pieces for them to come apart.